# Parallel RC circuit in feedback reading line

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm reviewing an [MC33810 evaluation board datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/KT33810UG1.pdf). On page 18, a parallel RC circuit is used in the feedback line, and I don't understand why. What is the purpose of this structure, whose image I have added below?

[image: Circuit Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The resistor divider causes the feedback signal to have a fairly high impedance.  The capacitor lowers this impedance at high frequency and shortens the rise time of the signal driving your feedback comparator.  Otherwise, the input capacitance combined with the feedback resistance would have a longer rise time, which would result in a delay that would occur while the input capacitance is charged through the feedback resistor up to the comparator threshold.

Comment: Since this is not available on the integrated Ltspice, I tried to draw the feedback line (without transistor) and add this parallel RC circuit in series, but I could not get the desired result. I foresee an instantaneous voltage of around 400v coming from the coil to the feedback line, can't I simulate it this way? I tried but I couldn't see the result I wanted, what I want to do is to observe the effect of the RC circuit by trying the situations with or without this parallel RC circuit in the feedback line.

Comment: Since they specify the 10 pF capacitor in a circuit which is to provide a 10:1 divider, I would assume 100 pf as the IC's input capacitance.  So I would simulate the FB pins as 100 pf capacitors.